# Clearing ::usage message

Tags: message-coding, clear

After having assigned the usage message to `f` using

```
ClearAll@f;
f::usage=ToString@RandomInteger@{10^10,10^11};
```

the mouseover message is stuck at the first assignment while `?f` shows the freshest usage message.

How to clear and reassign the usage message so even mouseover is updated?

---

Env:
Mathematica 12.0 on Win10

Comment: You have use `Remove` to get rid of usage messages.

Comment: @m_goldberg works! I'll accept if you answer... why doesn't ClearAll work though?

Answer (score 6):

It seems one can use the following to force the front-end to update the usage templates (starting in version 12.0):

```
FE`CacheTemplateAndUsage["f"]
```

Please note that the front-end will not update the templates even if you set a new usage message. Simply call the above again to force the update once again.

Comment: I think the packet this calls has existed since 11

Comment: @b3m2a1 For me, it doesn't seem to work: I get "Could not process unknown packet "CacheTemplateAndUsagePacket"" if I try it in 11.3. Am I missing something?

Comment: not really sure but I think it it did work